# Why is it necessary to explicity require jquery-ui in Shiny

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny

I'm running into an issue where I need to explicitly require the jquery-ui in order to use the function `progressbar`.  But, the shiny jquery build includes everything except datetime.  Why does the following only work if the line including jquery-ui is included?

```
library(shiny)

js <- "
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').append('<div id=\"progressbar\"></div>');
    $('#progressbar').progressbar({ value: 50 });
})
$(function() {
    var value = $('#progressbar').progressbar( 'value' );
    alert(value);
})
"

ui <- bootstrapPage(
    ## *** uncomment this line and progressbar works ***
    ## tags$head(tags$script(src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js")),
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js)))
    ## tags$head(tags$script(src='http://localhost:8080/skewer'))  # debugging
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Why does it work if you include jQuery ui? Because it was built to use it?

Comment: Does shiny include just jQuery? jQuery core does not have UI components.

Comment: I don't think jquery-ui is loaded by shiny, only jquery core